# Ruby on Rails content_tag options hash - setting a boolean html attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, html-helper, view-helpers

Boolean attributes, as defined in the html 5 draft specification:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#boolean-attributes

> The presence of a boolean attribute on
>   an element represents the true value,
>   and the absence of the attribute
>   represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value
>   must either be the empty string or a
>   value that is an ASCII
>   case-insensitive match for the
>   attribute's canonical name, with no
>   leading or trailing whitespace.

My page is using the html5 DTD.  I'm attempting to use the content_tag view helper in a helper of my own, but am having issues with passing boolean attributes to it.

Specifically this is my helper:

```
def itemscope(type, options = {}, &block)
  content_tag(
    :div, {
      :itemscope => true,
      :itemtype => data_definition_url(type)
    }.merge(options),
    true,
    &block
  )
end

def data_definition_url(type)
  "http://data-vocabulary.org/#{type}"
end
```

in my view, let's say I call it like this (I'm using haml):

```
= itemscope("Organization") do
  %h1 Here's some content
```

This is what I would want it to render:

```
<div itemscope itemtype='http://data-vocabulary.org/Organization'>
  <h1>Here's some content</h1>
</div>
```

But this is what I'm actually getting:

```
<div itemscope='true' itemtype='http://data-vocabulary.org/Organization'>
  <h1>Here's some content</h1>
</div>
```

Which is invalid markup according to the w3 specification.  Legal values for boolean attributes are either the name of the attribute itself, or no value at all.

It's annoying because I can change the `:itemscope => true` to `:checked => true` and it will correctly render the attribute as `checked='checked'` in the attribute list of the div element.

I'd prefer it to render the minimized version of just `itemscope`...but I'm not sure how to do *that* using the content_tag options.  I could very easily send :itemscope => 'itemscope' but it's difficult to say if that will be correctly interpreted by google since all of their examples and specifications show the minimized versions.  See here:  http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=146861 to see what these properties are and why I'm using them (Microdata format)

Anyone know how I can effectively get any attribute sent a true or false (ruby boolean) value in content_tag to render without any value instead of trying to stringify the boolean value?  Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like a great idea for a patch :)  Though the patch would be for HAML in this case, not Rails.

Comment: No, the problem lies with Rails' content_tag helper and related functions, not HAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following content into an initializer called `config/initializers/boolean_attributes.rb`

```
# add any other boolean attributes to the %w() below to make them work like checked.
BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES = %w(itemscope).to_set
BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES.merge(BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES.map {|attribute| attribute.to_sym })
ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper::BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES.merge(BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES)
```

Et Voila! Restart Rails and you should be good to go. I don't know how to make the thing just add a blank attribute, just how to make it work like checked, disabled, readonly, etc...

Comment: I'll give this a shot - but it would be nice if it were smart enough to see the value 'true' and just know what you wanted =p

Comment: indeed, we get so used to "rails magic" when it doesn't do what we expect its disappointing.  but I think it does this for a reason, since setting custom attributes (think "data-is_active") to true we would expect in javascript, for instance, to see a true or false value on that attribute rather than "data-is_active" == "data-is_active"

Comment: I agree with @nzifnab, it should be smart enough to treat it as a compliant boolean HTML attribute if you provide a boolean Ruby value (true or false). If you want the literal string 'true' or 'false', then supply the Ruby values 'true' or 'false'!

Answer (score 3):

the hacky but easy way: `content_tag('div itemscope', ...)`